# Avery Easy Peel Label Sorter Won't Install

Tags: installation, microsoft-word, installer, label

Avery has a program called [Avery Easy Peel Label Sorter](http://www.avery.com/avery/en_us/Templates-&-Software/Software/Avery-Easy-Peel-Label-Sorter.htm).  It's for users with Word documents of labels laid out across rows but who need to have them listed in columns.

I cannot get it to install.

I get this message:

> Avery Easy Peel Label Sorter -
>   InstallShield Wizard
>
> Some files are locked. Labler can not
>   be installed.  Please reboot your
>   computer/nasdsadadsda

[image: Avery Easy Peel Label Sorter - InstallShield Wizard]

Rebooting doesn't work.  "Run as Administrator" doesn't work.

I've got Word 2007 on Windows Vista.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) would help you find which file handles it is trying to open. Then you can use [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) on them.

Comment: You can also use Process Explorer to close a file handle.